# Topcoat/Phonegap Navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cordova, topcoat

I'm switching from using JQM and Phonegap to using Topcaot and a few smaller libraries to take care of transitions and such. One thing I haven't found a micro-library for is the navigation.

While many site I've seen say to create the UI and content dynamically through javascript, it does seem like a daunting task do to the amount of pages I would need to create. Similar to JQM, I want to be able to separate my different pages as different html files that ajax load them into the DOM, but in an optimized way that is fast and doesn't cary the weight of JQM.

TO anyones knowledge does such a library exist or would this be a library I would have to write? It doesn't seem like it would be an overly complicated task, especially if I would use jquery. Any ideas of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try angularjs. Here there's an example with topcoat: http://coenraets.org/blog/2013/11/sample-mobile-application-with-angularjs/
Angularjs is very different from JQM but you should give it a try.

Otherwise, if you don't like angularjs you can find a more traditional approach at this page: http://coenraets.org/blog/2013/03/hardware-accelerated-page-transitions-for-mobile-web-apps-phonegap-apps/

Hope this helps

Comment: Angular looks good. I'm still on the fence about either Angular or Backbone. Opinion? Thanks for the point in the right direction

Comment: You are welcome! I haven't tried backbone, so sorry, I can't help you here. Anyway, googling about this it seems to me that angularjs has a slight preference.

Answer (score 1):

Here you are - new plugin based on coenraets css transitional solution: https://github.com/linslin/pagingSlider

Features:

- Paging with pagingSlider
- default pageSlider actions
- Pagebrowser
- Totaly plugable like pageSlider
- if you want, pagemenu to switch directly to a page
- touch events

Answer (score 1):

Consider looking at [Topcoat Touch](https://topcoattouch.com) ([Github Project](https://github.com/kriserickson/topcoat-touch)), it is basically a micro library for transitions and events (5k minified and gzipped) -- full disclosure, I am the author of Topcoat Touch.

It is a very simple framework that uses Topcoat to create the UI, inspired by [jQT](http://jqtjs.com/) and to a lesser extent [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/). It can be either a single html document with multiple pages contained within the same document, or using a collection of controllers and templates. It uses a collection of optional libraries to provide most of the functionality for a mobile framework and has a [generator](https://github.com/kriserickson/generator-topcoat-touch) for [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) to get the scaffolding up quickly.

Comment: This looks awesome! I like the use of the data-rel attributes to create the links to the different pages. Very nice framework for a fast and clean app. Definitely will use down the road.

Answer (score -1):

I haven't used it, but Kendo UI Mobile is similar to JQM and may fit your needs: http://www.kendoui.com/mobile.aspx